# Non Editable Footer in HTML / CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a serious mental blank on how to do this, I remember I was able to at some point but forgot the code I found and can't find it anymore.

I need to make a section of my HTML file unchangeable. I have made a FREE HTML template for users to download off my site but I wish to 'force' them to have a link back to my email in the footer after their copyright.

So I need some code that can work with HTML5/CSS3 and Javascript and that does not rely on PHP or any server side scripting.

If anyone can help this would be great... or if you can offer any other way to do this would be great also for my future projects

Comment: That's not really practically possible. There's nothing stopping people who download the template to change or remove whatever blocks you put there.

Comment: If something (HTML, CSS, JS, imgs, audio, video) is displayed in a browser, then there's no way to stop people from copying it without your permission.

Comment: @Juhana Yeah I understand this, was hoping for an easy solution without having to go into server side coding to have 'something close' to this.

Comment: @oleq Yes I know this lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are releasing source code, you can never guarantee that no one will edit it. As HTML/CSS/JS can only be distributed in source code form (at least when you want to display it in a web browser), you can never be guaranteed that it will not be altered.

Your best option is to use a license that requires the user to attribute the work to you in the manner you specified (in this case, a link back to your email in the footer, well readable). It will, however, not stop people with criminal intent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have this currently.. but as the human race shows they would rather take it out and claim it as their own rather than credit the original person who created it.... have to live with these things i guess

Comment: You said it better :)

Answer (score 1):

As you are releasing source code, your best bet would be to use a license with an added condition that your email be included in the footer.

---

With regards to your problem about the human race, perhaps an email in the footer is too conspicuous for their purposes. If you give them more freedom on how to give you credit I believe most will happily comply.

Comment: Yeah, i currently have this happening and was looking for an alternate way to have it there... seen it done before but that was for more server side code that many people may not know how to remove unless they have good knowledge in coding.